# MySQL Utilities cannot connect mysql via login-paths

Tags: mysql

When using mysql utilities following the official doc [2.2.1.1 Use login-paths (.mylogin.cnf)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/mysql-utils-intro-connspec-mylogin.cnf.html) as follow:

1.Use the mysql_config_editor tool to add the connection information

```
$ mysql_config_editor set --login-path=db01 --host=localhost --user=root --port=3306 --password
```

2.

```
$ mysql_config_editor print --login-path=db01
[db01]
user = root
password = *****
host = localhost
port = 3306
```

3.But when I try to connect to mysql via `mysqlserverinfo` command, I got the Access denied error:

```
$ mysqlserverinfo --server=db01 --format=vertical
ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' using password: YES
```

Howerver, the following command can login in to mysql：

```
$ mysql --login-path=db01
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 766424
Server version: 5.6.30-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log (Ubuntu)
...
```

And also, when I follow [2.2.1.2 Use a Configuration File](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/mysql-utils-intro-connspec-config_file.html) with the same connection information in a configuration file `server.cnf`, it works:

```
$ mysqlserverinfo --server=server.cnf[db01] --format=vertical
# Source on localhost: ... connected.
*************************       1. row *************************
...
```

Cloud anyone point out what is wrong with the logins-paths approach?